# javascript anchor avoid scroll to top on click

Tags: javascript

I created a function in javascript that i add to an anchor as such

javascript :

```
somefunction = function () {alert('foo')}
```

html :

```
<a href="#" onclick="return somefunction()">anchor</a>
```

everytime i click on the anchor the function executes but the screen scrolls to the top

I know i could do this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return somefunction()">anchor</a>
```

but I have seen the first option implemented without this hick up of scrolling up

is there any trick to it?

thank you

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The onclick causes the page to resubmit, therefore scrolling to the top.

You need the onclick event to return a false in order to avoid the postback.

This can be done by changing your function to return a false:

```
somefunction = function () {alert('foo'); return false;}
```

Or to change the link and onClick event to do so:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="somefunction(); return false;">anchor</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

The trick is that your onclick returns the value of `somefunction`, so that if you make sure `somefunction` always `return false`, then the event will return false as well, and cancel the default behavior of the anchor.

So this should solve your problem:

```
somefunction = function () { alert('foo'); return false; }
```

But I should mention that when there is an error somewhere in `somefunction`, the rest of the javascript will not execute, and the browser will still follow the link to `#`. It is advisable, therefore, to use `javascript:void(0)` instead, as this will rid you of that problem.

Answer (score 2):

Return `false` from your onclick handler, e.g.:

```
<a href="#" onclick="somefunction(); return false;">anchor</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `somefunction()` return `false`, or you need to explicitly add `return false` to your `onclick` handler.  For example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="somefunction(); return false;">anchor</a>
```

This will have the browser ignore the `href` portion of the link when someone clicks on it.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the question is asked for JavaScript, but if anyone would like to do it in jQuery then it is pretty simple.

You can give your a tag an id and reference it in jQuery to do a certain action.

All you need to do, - to avoid the scroll to top is to disable the default action of the a tag.

Code:

```
$( "#a-tag-id" ).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert( "Hello World" );
    });
```