# How to stop page load while clicking on link with href=#?

Tags: javascript, html

i have FAQ page with more than 20 questions.it works as when i click on any question,it shows answer,when i click question again it hides the answer.i used javascript which show/hide the division.

```
<script>
function showHideDiv(id){
var obj = document.getElementById(id);
if (obj.style.display=="none"){
  obj.style.display='block';
} else if(obj.style.display=="block"){
  obj.style.display='none';
}
}
</script>
```

and here is the html Code,

```
<h5><a href="#" onclick="showHideDiv('div-7')">Question No.7</a></h5>
    <div id="div-7" style="display:none;">Answer No.7</div><br>

    <h5><a href="#" onclick="showHideDiv('div-8')">Question No.8</a></h5>
    <div id="div-8" style="display:none;">Answer No.8</div><br>
```

Now the problem is when i click question 1 to 5,it works perfect,but when i scroll page down and click question no. 7 to 22,due to "#" in href attribute of ,page reloads and scroll back to top,instead of showing the opened answer.so i want something like the page should not be refreshed,but should stay on whichever question is clicked.

Comment: A bit of research and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084750/javascript-anchor-avoid-scroll-to-top-on-click) shows up.

Comment: thanks for finding it out, and sorry i repeated same question again.i couldnt found it on first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `return false` on click.

```
<h5><a href="#" onclick="showHideDiv('div-7'); return false;">Question No.7</a></h5>
```

or

```
<h5><a href="#" onclick="return showHideDiv('div-7')">Question No.7</a></h5>
```

and `return false` in `showHideDiv`