# How to make the browser scrollbar static

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have dynamically created textfields with the help of a click on an anchor.
Whenever I click on the anchor button the new textfield get created and like wise n number of textfield gets created per click on anchor.
My problem is with the scrollbar. Whenever the window size gets exceeded scrollbar comes into picture. Now after this when I scrolldown and click on the anchor the scrollbar doesnt remain static and it moves to the top. 
For creating a new textfield, I have to scrolldown again.

Can anyone of you help me how to make this scrollbar static so that it never scrolls to top automatically.

Regards,
Ethan

Comment: Post your code / jsfiddle. Not sure what you're trying to explain. :)

Comment: So what you're saying is when you add a textfield you want the page to automatically scroll to that textfield instead of having to do it manually?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript anchor avoid scroll to top on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084750/javascript-anchor-avoid-scroll-to-top-on-click)

Comment: No it was everytime I was adding the textfield, it was scrolling to the top- Major-mann has helped to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess you may have "#" as the href value in your link and your javascript tied up via onclick? This would cause the window to scroll to the top when the link is clicked.

The easiest way to remedy this is to remove the onclick attribute, and change the href attribute to the form "javascript: createTextBox()".

For example
From:

```
<a href="#" onclick="createTextBox();">Create</a>
```

To:

```
<a href="javascript: createTextBox();">Create</a>
```

Comment: I am checking it, I think you may be right.

Comment: Yeah, now the scrollbar is not moving at top. Is there anyother way coz I have to do a lot of changes now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am saved now :)

Comment: As for another way, you could do a setTimeout(function() { window.scrollTo(0, 1000000); }, 10); or something like that at the end of your code to make it scroll down after processing the link

Comment: Thanks, I did not do much changes and let my code remain the same. Only thing I have modified is <a href="javascript: function createTextBox(){}">Create</a>

Comment: Another way would be bind a jquery click event on the anchor and pass an event to the callback and event.preventDefault()...

Comment: @AlexShilman This is much better than my proposed javascript solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="divForAnchor">
<a id="clickAnchor" href="#">Click to add a text box</a>
</div>
var counter = 0;

$('#clickAnchor').click(function(){
    var template = $("<p><input type='text' name='textbox "+counter+"'>");
    $('#clickAnchor').prepend(template);
    var containerHt = $('#divForAnchor').outerHeight();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: containerHt});
    counter++;
  });
```

In this code the text boxes are appended before the anchor tag. On adding the text boxes, the scroll bar automatically moves to the anchor tag when the window size exceeds. Hope this is useful to you.