# The page gets scrolled to the top if I apply height to the body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My problem is that I have a button on the html page, and when this button is clicked a popup box opens(covering the background), and to stop the background scroll I am applying this css:

```
windowHeight = $(window).height();
$("body").css({
    "height": windowHeight,
    "overflow": "hidden", 
    "overflow-y": "hidden"
});
```

Everything works perfectly but the page gets scrolled to top. How do I prevent this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript anchor avoid scroll to top on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084750/javascript-anchor-avoid-scroll-to-top-on-click)

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that you change the `height`. You don't need to set the `height`, making the `body` `overflow: hidden` should be enough.

CSS:

```
.locked {
  overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$("body").addClass("locked");
```

Try it: http://jsbin.com/tapagexope/1/edit?html,css,js,output *(Click the body)*

Tested in FF 34 and Chrome 38.

---

Note that you should position your overlay in a container that is `position: fixed` and `left, top, bottom, right` are all `0`, covering the whole viewport. Within that box you can center your overlay element.

Answer (score 0):

I actually already wrote a jQuery plugin to solve this exact problem: [`jquery-disablescroll`](https://github.com/ultrapasty/jquery-disablescroll)

Using the plugin script, when the popup opens call:

```
$(window).disablescroll();
```

When the popup is closed, enable scrolling again by calling:

```
$(window).disablescroll("undo");
```

[Here's the example.](http://jsfiddle.net/3n34qw6r/)