# Avoid jumping to the page top?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the statement I have used

```
   <a href="#" onclick="return false">show_all</a>
```

I tried

1. `onclick=preventDefault();`
2. `onclick="return false";`

But it's still jumping to the top of the page, please suggest.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084750/javascript-anchor-avoid-scroll-to-top-on-click

Answer (score 0):

`preventDefault()` is attached to an `event` - you need to specify that afaik.

In this example the function is attached inline

```
<a href='#' onclick='myfunc(event)'>Show all</a>

function myfunc( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    /* rest of the function */
}
```

or, perhaps something like

```
<a href='#'>Show all</a>
var col=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for( var n in col ) if( col[n].nodeType==1 ) col[n].onclick=myfunc;
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to avoid jumping to the page top when anchor was clicked with
>   empty hash?

```
window.onhashchange = function(e){
   if (!location.hash){
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;   
   };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return false;">show_all</a>
```